# Open Url in default web browser

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new in react-native and i want to open **url** in **default browser like Chrome in Android and iPhone** both.

We open url via intent in Android same like functionality i want to achieve.

I have search many times but it will give me the result of *Deepklinking*.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You should use [`Linking`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking).

Example from the docs:

```
class OpenURLButton extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = { url: React.PropTypes.string };
  handleClick = () => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(this.props.url).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(this.props.url);
      } else {
        console.log("Don't know how to open URI: " + this.props.url);
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
        {" "}
        <View style={styles.button}>
          {" "}<Text style={styles.text}>Open {this.props.url}</Text>{" "}
        </View>
        {" "}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an example you can try on [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/rJm_YkqyW):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title="Click me" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: @RajKumarN, how would this work if you have an app that grabs news articles and you want to open the news articles' hyperlinks in a separate browser?

Comment: Check this out, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest. This can be helpful @Daniel

Comment: @RajKumarN How can we open the external URL inside the app not redirecting to the browser?

Comment: The [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) at the top of this answer no longer works. Gotta love the irony :)

Comment: @CalebKoch Dropping the `.html` at the end of the URL makes the link work again. Updated my answer, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 23):

A simpler way which eliminates checking if the app can open the url.

```
  loadInBrowser = () => {
    Linking.openURL(this.state.url).catch(err => console.error("Couldn't load page", err));
  };
```

Calling it with a button.

```
<Button title="Open in Browser" onPress={this.loadInBrowser} />
```

Comment: How do I handle null values? let's say I'm receiving URL from backend but it returned null instead of a string, the app is crashing.

Comment: @ASN You do that check prior to passing that url to the `openURL` method. For example: `If (this.state.url) Linking.openURL(this.state.url)`. You can also put the catch clause to use if you don't want to check prior.

Comment: Yeah that is how I handled it. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi! Just a question,
What do you suggest to do for android if app is selected to open by default and I need to open the same link but in browser?

Comment: simple, short, useful solution, can you comment about it shows blank screen when I comeback manually from browser to app.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```js
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Linking } from "react-native";
OpenWEB = () => {
  Linking.openURL(url);
};

const App = () => {
  return <View onPress={() => OpenWeb}>OPEN YOUR WEB</View>;
};
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

In React 16.8+, the following can be used to create an `ExternalLinkBtn` component, similar to an `a` tag on the web. The link will be opened externally in the default browser.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Linking } from 'react-native';

const ExternalLinkBtn = (props) => {
  return <Button
            title={props.title}
            onPress={() => {
                Linking.openURL(props.url)
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error("Failed opening page because: ", err)
                    alert('Failed to open page')
                })}}
          />
}
```

Below is an example of using our `ExternalLinkBtn` in a component

```
export default function exampleUse() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ExternalLinkBtn title="Example Link" url="https://example.com" />
    </View>
  )
}
```