# How to pass an object with onClick React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have an object in an external file and I want to pass the `url` into the button `onClick` but I do not know to pass the value.

Object:

```
const ProjectLists = [

    {
        id: "4",
        iconImage: "",
        name: "Simple",
        description: "Simple is a corporate responsive template and the absolutely clean & modern template theme for your business. The theme was built by Foundation Framework and take advantages of it features: grid system, typography, buttons, form, UI element, section and more.",
        technologies: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript",
        href: "http://striped-dolls.surge.sh"
    }
]

export default ProjectLists;
```

How to pass `ProjectLists.map((project, i) =>` `href` in `map()` into `<button>`

```
class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {ProjectLists.map((project, i) =>

        <section className='section'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-sm'>
              <div className='content-left'>
                <p key={project.id + i}>
                  {project.iconImage}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-sm-8'>
              <div className='content-right text-left'>
                <h1>{project.name}</h1>
                <p>{project.description}</p>
                <p>Technologies: {project.technologies}</p>
                <button type='submit' onClick=() => </button>>View live</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You want to redirect to the link or use button for this purpose.

Comment: you can use from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804032/open-url-in-default-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use "a" tag for this purpose.

```
<a href={project.href}></a>
```

If you want to use onClick in your button, then you can try this.

```
onClick={() => { window.location.href = project.href }}
```

Comment: This solution is working but I would like to know how to pass `{project.href}` in `onClick()`. Could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra data in your map using arrow functions:

```
{ProjectLists.map(project =>
  <button onClick={onProjectClick(project)}>View live</button>
}

// e.g.
onProjectClick = project => event => {
  console.log(project.description);
  navigateTo(project.href);
}
```

I noticed your button has `type="submit"` so more the correct event to handle is `onSubmit` on the form element however as this handles pressing the Return key for example (it's not essential though).

Comment: Thank you but I want to pass it in the `<Button>` with `onClick`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, I just showed you how to pass the project data into the button onClick event??

Comment: I am a beginner with React. I am sorry if I do not understand it all.

Where do I add this function to the `class Projects`? 

```
onProjectClick = project => event => {
  console.log(project.description);
  navigateTo(project.href);
}
```

Comment: I add `onProjectClick` before `render()` but it keeps show errors!

Comment: You should add it on the same level as render() (before or after shouldn't matter) but maybe you are not using `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in your project, in that cause you would get an error. I highly recommend using it as it makes working with event callbacks a lot cleaner in React

Comment: For beginner, always  use https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app, then you dont have to worry about babel most of the time

Answer (score 0):

```
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }
  setRedirect = (href) => {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
```

Call the `setRedirect` function

```
<button onClick={()=>this.setRedirect(project.href)}>View live</button>
```