# How do I open link from data.json in react-native using button?

Tags: react-native

I want to open the link in the data.json file that I created in react-native and I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

```
<TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.play}
                    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('props.song.musicUrl') }
                    
                >
                <Text style ={styles.play_button}>Press Here</Text>
```

`{
"id":0,

```
    "imageUrl":"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/94/28/8f/94288fe9af3ede8f4e07505da921f373.jpg",
    "musicUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6vXWtNZu0c"

},`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps to do this (I think you've already achieved 1 and 2):

- First read the contents of the json file
- Get the link from the json
- Open link with `Linking`

1. To read the contents of the json file [Fetch data from local json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native)

   ```
   const customData = require('./customData.json');
   ```
2. Get the link from the json

   ```
   const link = customData.musicUrl
   ```
3. Use Linking

   ```
   Linking.openURL(link)
   ```

---

In your case,

```
   Linking.openURL(props.song.musicUrl) // <- Remove quotes
```

Since adding quotes creates a String, you're trying to open the link `'props.song.musicUrl'` instead of the link inside the JSON.

You can look here for guidance ([OpenURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804295/15261366))