# How to Open URL "on click" after Scanning a QR Code in React-Native Android App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React-Native & created a QR Scanner App. After scanning want to open url onClick/onPress.

[image: Here is the image of my code]

-- Here is the code

onSuccess = (e) => {
setResult(e.data)
setScan(false)
}

// Start scanner
startScan = () => {
setScan(true)
setResult()
}

```
            <QRCodeScanner
              reactivate={true}
              showMarker={true}
              ref={(node) => { this.scanner = node }}
              onRead={this.onSuccess}
              topContent={
                <Text style={styles.centerText}>
                  Scan your QRCode!
                </Text>
              }
              bottomContent={
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonTouchable} onPress={() => setScan(false)}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Cancel Scan</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              }
            />
```

Comment: Hi, can you give more detail about the URL that you want to open? Or the `onClick` function that you want to be executed?

Comment: Hello @Michael Harley.... Yaaaa  there is a QR Code scanner app.... When we scan any QR Code... then related to that QR Code a URL has been generated.

Now i want that when i click on that generated URL, that page'll be open in the browser

Comment: I think you can use `Linking` from `react-native` to open the new browser, on your `onSuccess` method.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804032/open-url-in-default-web-browser

Comment: yes @MichaelHarley but Linking directly open that page but i want after click on generated url then open that page

Comment: Then you can try to render the URL first with `Text` component (after a success scan), and trigger the `Linking` with `onPress` props from the `Text`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/how-does-one-display-a-hyperlink-in-react-native-app

Comment: ohk thanks @MichaelHarley i'll try this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one Display a Hyperlink in React Native App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/how-does-one-display-a-hyperlink-in-react-native-app)

Comment: i try it but don't know how to render my data into text block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me help you

Your code might look like this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [scan, setScan] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  function onSuccess(e){
    setResult(e.data);
    setScan(false);
  }

  function onURLPress(){
    Linking.openURL(result);
  }

  return (
    <QRCodeScanner
      reactivate={true}
      showMarker={true}
      ref={(node) => { this.scanner = node }}
      onRead={this.onSuccess}
      topContent={
        <Text style={styles.centerText}>
          Scan your QRCode!
        </Text>
      }
      bottomContent={
        <Text style={[styles.buttonText, styles.buttonTouchable]} onPress={() => setScan(false)}>Cancel Scan</Text>
      }
    />

    {/* This is where you show the generated url */}
    {result && <Text onPress={onURLPress}>{result}</Text>}
  )
}
```

Note that you can change your `bottomContent` Text to use onPress as well, instead of using `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: thanku @Michael Harley but it's not working... output remain same... didn't redirect when click on url

Comment: @ShrutiGupta Any error message that you can find? does the URL value available? you need to debug it and see the next problem/error, then fix the new problem.

Comment: no there is no error occur.... output remain same...

Comment: I will need more detail about the URL that you are using, it is possible that the URL is invalid.

Comment: no URL is perfectly fine because URL is not static... it is dynamic... like when we are scan any QR code then URL is generated... and when we are using linking direct on e.data then scanned URL is open